# Reading videos from mubi.com fails on Raspberry Pi with videojs errors

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming, html5-video, cdn, video.js

When I try to play movies from mubi.com on the Raspberry Pi 4, the video won't start and I see several videojs error messages in the web console of the browser. I tried two browsers, chromium and firefox, and two operating systems, Raspbian and Arch Linux. On both OS and browsers, playing videos from Youtube, dailymotion or vimeo works fine, only mubi gives issues. I tried using browser plugins h264ify and decentraleyes but I keep getting the following errors. On Linux desktop I have never had any problem playing from mubi.com with any browser. Can someone help understand what these errors mean ?

```
Resource URL: https://mubi.com/films/kingyo/watch
Source Map URL: manifest-0c2854bad8183a32f809.js.map
09:46:46.237 [clpp.player] Loading sources 
Array [ {…} ]

Object { drmtoday: {…} }
breadcrumbs.js:58
09:46:46.267 [clpp.player.utils.video_events] Player state change: IDLE -> PREPARING breadcrumbs.js:58
09:46:46.825 [clpp.abr] creating bandwidth meter: SLIDING_PERCENTILE breadcrumbs.js:58
Successfully compiled asm.js code (total compilation time 74ms) mubi_player-3808cb2e6df5273c018b.js
Request to access cookie or storage on “<URL>?” was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is enabled. 9
MouseEvent.mozPressure is deprecated. Use PointerEvent.pressure instead. clpp.min.js:26:17357
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:0 MEDIA_ERR_CUSTOM) <empty string> 
Object { code: 0, instanceof: "CLPPError", message_: "", group: {…}, name: "REQUESTED_KEY_SYSTEM_CONFIG_UNAVAILABLE", errCode: 6001, severity: "WARNING", parentError: {}, ts: 1587808013074, processed: true, … }
breadcrumbs.js:58
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:0 MEDIA_ERR_CUSTOM) <empty string>
Object { code: 0, instanceof: "CLPPError", message_: "CDN switch failed", group: {…}, name: "CDN_SWITCH_FAILED", errCode: 137, severity: "WARNING", parentError: {}, ts: 1587808013170, processed: true, … }
breadcrumbs.js:58 
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:0 MEDIA_ERR_CUSTOM) <empty string>
Object { code: 0, instanceof: "CLPPError", message_: "CDN switch failed", group: {…}, name: "CDN_SWITCH_FAILED", errCode: 137, severity: "WARNING", parentError: {}, ts: 1587808013200, processed: true, … }
breadcrumbs.js:58 
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:0 MEDIA_ERR_CUSTOM) <empty string>
Object { code: 0, instanceof: "CLPPError", message_: "CDN switch failed", group: {…}, name: "CDN_SWITCH_FAILED", errCode: 137, severity: "WARNING", parentError: {}, ts: 1587808013225, processed: true, … }
breadcrumbs.js:58 
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:0 MEDIA_ERR_CUSTOM) <empty string>
Object { code: 0, instanceof: "CLPPError", message_: "CDN switch failed", group: {…}, name: "CDN_SWITCH_FAILED", errCode: 137, severity: "WARNING", parentError: {}, ts: 1587808013250, processed: true, … }
breadcrumbs.js:58
```

Comment: This question's probably better suited to [su] than [so], but from the key systems error messages it's a DRM issue. This may be relevant: https://blog.vpetkov.net/2019/07/12/netflix-and-spotify-on-a-raspberry-pi-4-with-latest-default-chromium/

Comment: Yes indeed that was a DRM issue, which was not clear for from the error messages. The blog article helped me setup DRM and I am not able to watch it. Thanks!